# How do I always show (or autohide) menu items in Unity?

Tags: unity, menu

Is there any way to have the menu items on window menus always visible? I hate the whole hide and seek thing and have searched Google and here but I'm unable to find anything on how to make them stay visible all the time.

Thanks

Answer (score 57, accepted):

## 16.04 and later (Unity 7)

In addition to the gsettings option introduced in 15.04 (below), this same capability has been added to the Settings - Appearances window (click the gear icon top-right of the screen)

[image]

## 14.04, 15.04, 15.10

15.04 now has the ability to toggle the global menu as well as the local integrated menus (Via System Settings - Appearance - Behaviour tab) to be permanently on or off.

If you are running a fully up-to-date version of 14.04, this same ability has been backported.

To switch on permanently:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true
```

To switch off i.e. to autohide:

```
gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus false
```

Comment: Thats the one buddy :) 'gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true' I'd already done the appearance setting change. Is it possible to still have it display the windows name though?

Answer (score 9):

Go to Ubuntu software centre and download a tool named `Unity tweak tool`

If it's downloaded, launch it and choose `Window controls` menu from there.
[image: Unity tweak tool]
In there, click on `show menu` button, and close the tweak program.
[image] 
Reopen all windows and it should be working.

Also, please let me know if it did not work!

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 here and it didn't work =|

Comment: Not sure maybe something has been changed with the feature. If I turned it on my self, then the menu is shown only when you open a new application and it is shown only for a couple of seconds. After that it dissapears. Without the option, the menu will not show at start, you have to mouse over. You could make a bug report about it I guess.

Comment: Hmm, interestingly the combination of two answers worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  Besides doing what this answer suggests I also did what @fossfreedom says below, i.e. : `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true`  (which worked without complaining that 'No such key ').

I tried  two apps after doing this, Pidgin and Thundebird, and both of them had the Locally integrated menus permanently visible after  restarting them. Before doing the gsettings bit from command line I had the same behaviour as described by @Kaspar in the comment above.

Comment: gsettings and this one doesnt work in 14.04.

Comment: Hi Kaspar, I did what you explained here but it didn't work for me - After checking "Right" and "Show menu button" no change is seen (Ubuntu 15.10).

Comment: Looks at the answer below, that seems to be a newer one that applies to newer versions of Ubuntu. 16.04 is coming soon so I guess that would fix it for you when the upgrade comes.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 20.04 go to Settings

Settings -> Appearance, then disable the feature, Auto-hide the Dock as shown in below image.

[image]