# How to have "File, Edit, View, ..." menu integrated in windows

Tags: 14.04, unity, window

[image]

Hello, I was wondering how to move these options from global top menu to actual window, when window is not maximized.

Does anybody have a clue how to do it? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I always show menu items in Unity?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/541449/how-do-i-always-show-menu-items-in-unity)

Comment: Actually, this question has never been asked before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hit the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to open the Dash and search for "Appearance". Once the window opens, go to "Behavior" followed by "Show the menus for a window" and select the "In the window's title bar" radio button.

Comment: There is no such thing in 14.04.

Comment: @Pilot6 Good point, I hadn't noticed the 14.04 tag. Any idea if it is possible using the Unity Tweak Tool?

Comment: I found in my 14.04 that it is available here too now. Probably after some update.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks for checking! I guess I lucked out. :)