# 17.10 - Lost Chrome menu bar

Tags: google-chrome, 17.10

As you can see the console has its menubar, but Chrome does not (it was there before the upgrade). 
I tried switching to/from Gtk+/Classic look in the chrome settings

[image]

Turns out things are pretty weird. Based on the suggestion in the comment from Yaksha, I downloaded the unity tweak tool and the icon I need is not present!

[image]

Comment: Can you check by setting **System Settings>Appearance>Behaviour>Menu Visibility** to Always Displayed?

Comment: where do I start to find **System Settings**. I can open the Ubuntu **Settings** but that has no appearance section, while in chrome there in **Settings>Appearance** but no **Behaviour**

Comment: Do it according to this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/610237. Run the command listed in this answer, if the GUI option does not work

Comment: I too don't have that option in the **tweak tool**. Without worrying about that, did you try this command that the answer says? `gsettings set com.canonical.Unity always-show-menus true`

Comment: sorry, I should have mentioned that that did not help (unless you think I need to reboot first)